# frequent class loading causes tomcat connector thread wait in JRuby web application

Tags: java, tomcat, jruby

Our team has a web application developed with JRuby, and running on Tomcat 7.0.42 + Oracle JVM 1.8.0.51.  The application has a master wrapper servlet, and the servlet acts as proxy to route the requests to the JRuby script handling them

Now we hit a concurrent problem, that Tomcat connector execution threads are waiting, and only 1-2 threads are working at most time. Below is native thread stack shows what the problem thread is waiting for:

```
----------------- 67 -----------------
0x00007f579d5c85bc      __pthread_cond_wait + 0xcc
0x00007f579c711028      _ZN7Monitor5ILockEP6Thread + 0x228
0x00007f579c71119f      _ZN7Monitor4lockEP6Thread + 0x10f
0x00007f579c86a57a      _ZN16SystemDictionary30resolve_instance_class_or_nullEP6Symbol6HandleS2_P6Thread + 0x86a
0x00007f579c86ac58      _ZN16SystemDictionary21resolve_super_or_failEP6SymbolS1_6HandleS2_bP6Thread + 0x2d8
0x00007f579c2a10c7      _ZN15ClassFileParser14parseClassFileEP6SymbolP15ClassLoaderData6Handle11KlassHandleP13GrowableArrayIS4_ER13TempNewSymbolbP6Thread + 0xfd7
0x00007f579c8661ef      _ZN16SystemDictionary19resolve_from_streamEP6Symbol6HandleS2_P15ClassFileStreambP6Thread + 0x17f
0x00007f579c547b0e      _ZL23jvm_define_class_commonP7JNIEnv_PKcP8_jobjectPKaiS4_S2_hP6Thread + 0x2ae
0x00007f579c54ceb1      JVM_DefineClassWithSource + 0xe1
0x00007f579b58eb45      Java_java_lang_ClassLoader_defineClass1 + 0x155
0x00007f57854db64b      <Unknown compiled code>

----------------- 111 -----------------
0x00007f579d5c85bc      __pthread_cond_wait + 0xcc
0x00007f579c711028      _ZN7Monitor5ILockEP6Thread + 0x228
0x00007f579c71119f      _ZN7Monitor4lockEP6Thread + 0x10f
0x00007f579c865aab      _ZN16SystemDictionary21define_instance_classE19instanceKlassHandleP6Thread + 0x34b
0x00007f579c866396      _ZN16SystemDictionary19resolve_from_streamEP6Symbol6HandleS2_P15ClassFileStreambP6Thread + 0x326
0x00007f579c547b0e      _ZL23jvm_define_class_commonP7JNIEnv_PKcP8_jobjectPKaiS4_S2_hP6Thread + 0x2ae
0x00007f579c54ceb1      JVM_DefineClassWithSource + 0xe1
0x00007f579b58eb45      Java_java_lang_ClassLoader_defineClass1 + 0x155
0x00007f57854db64b      <Unknown compiled code>
```

After deep dive into the JVM code, we find some clue:
Every time JRuby script is to be executed, it will be interpreted and translate into a class. To load this class, a JVM JNI native interface ClassLoader.defineClass1 is called. This native logic of JVM requires exclusive locking during define a class or dynamic invocation of methods(logic into JVM SystemDictionary cpp class).

Therefore, we are thinking any ways to mitigate this performance problem, is there any way we could tune JRuby so that it will not load/unload the translated Class objects? or any other tuning methods could be suggested?

### Thanks !

Update the Tomcat executor thread java stack:

```
"http-bio-8080-exec-23" #212 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f0680004800 nid=0x1a16 runnable [0x00007f0669ebf000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
    at org.jruby.util.JRubyClassLoader.defineClass(JRubyClassLoader.java:173)
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InvocationMethodFactory.endClassWithBytes(InvocationMethodFactory.java:1459)
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InvocationMethodFactory.endCallWithBytes(InvocationMethodFactory.java:1443)
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InvocationMethodFactory.getCompiledMethod(InvocationMethodFactory.java:282)
    at org.jruby.runtime.Helpers.constructSingletonMethod(Helpers.java:2102)
    at org.jruby.runtime.Helpers.defs(Helpers.java:323)
    at rubyjit.Module$$extended_ae0875067076ab75e62753510e61fa82bf7d1b841680052247.__file__(/apps/tomcat7/webapps/calcengine/WEB-INF/classes/rubysrc/libs/calcengine/extrule.rb:80)
    at rubyjit.Module$$extended_ae0875067076ab75e62753510e61fa82bf7d1b841680052247.__file__(/apps/tomcat7/webapps/calcengine/WEB-INF/classes/rubysrc/libs/calcengine/extrule.rb)
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.JittedMethod.call(JittedMethod.java:181)
    at org.jruby.RubyClass.finvoke(RubyClass.java:742)
    at org.jruby.runtime.Helpers.invoke(Helpers.java:503)
    at org.jruby.RubyBasicObject.callMethod(RubyBasicObject.java:363)
    at org.jruby.RubyBasicObject.extend(RubyBasicObject.java:2559)
    at org.jruby.RubyKernel.extend(RubyKernel.java:2213)
    at org.jruby.RubyKernel$INVOKER$s$0$0$extend.call(RubyKernel$INVOKER$s$0$0$extend.gen)
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.JavaMethod$JavaMethodN.call(JavaMethod.java:665)
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DynamicMethod.call(DynamicMethod.java:206)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:168)
    at rubyjit.Module$$pickrules4Order_c2ca99d7f8cf0e55c79920f16524fb2bc5fa6e261680052247.block_0$RUBY$__file__(/apps/tomcat7/webapps/calcengine/WEB-INF/classes/rubysrc/libs/extservice/rulepickservice.rb:31)
    at rubyjit$Module$$pickrules4Order_c2ca99d7f8cf0e55c79920f16524fb2bc5fa6e261680052247$block_0$RUBY$__file__.call(rubyjit$Module$$pickrules4Order_c2ca99d7f8cf0e55c79920f16524fb2bc5fa6e261680052247$block_0$RUBY$__file__)
    at org.jruby.runtime.CompiledBlock19.yield(CompiledBlock19.java:159)
    at org.jruby.runtime.CompiledBlock19.yield(CompiledBlock19.java:145)
    at org.jruby.runtime.Block.yieldArray(Block.java:158)
    at org.jruby.RubyEnumerable$25.call(RubyEnumerable.java:848)
    at org.jruby.runtime.CallBlock.yieldSpecific(CallBlock.java:76)
    at org.jruby.runtime.Block.yieldSpecific(Block.java:120)
    at rubyjit.Mongoid::Contextual::Mongo$$yield_document_c96fb4ff211b64934be321fa3a44264a996eff891680052247.__file__(/apps/tomcat7/webapps/calcengine/WEB-INF/lib/promotionlibs.jar!/gems/mongoid-4.0.2/lib/mongoid/contextual/mongo.rb:658)
    at rubyjit.Mongoid::Contextual::Mongo$$yield_document_c96fb4ff211b64934be321fa3a44264a996eff891680052247.__file__(/apps/tomcat7/webapps/calcengine/WEB-INF/lib/promotionlibs.jar!/gems/mongoid-4.0.2/lib/mongoid/contextual/mongo.rb)
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.JittedMethod.call(JittedMethod.java:201)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callBlock(CachingCallSite.java:177)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:183)
    at rubyjit.Mongoid::Contextual::Mongo$$each_2fb7a025221ceabc57ed6ee46d5f9169720ef1bd1680052247.block_0$RUBY$__file__(/apps/tomcat7/webapps/calcengine/WEB-INF/lib/promotionlibs.jar!/gems/mongoid-4.0.2/lib/mongoid/contextual/mongo.rb:123)
    at rubyjit$Mongoid::Contextual::Mongo$$each_2fb7a025221ceabc57ed6ee46d5f9169720ef1bd1680052247$block_0$RUBY$__file__.call(rubyjit$Mongoid::Contextual::Mongo$$each_2fb7a025221ceabc57ed6ee46d5f9169720ef1bd1680052247$block_0$RUBY$__file__)
    at org.jruby.runtime.CompiledBlock19.yield(CompiledBlock19.java:135)
    at org.jruby.runtime.CompiledBlock19.yieldSpecific(CompiledBlock19.java:97)
    at org.jruby.runtime.Block.yieldSpecific(Block.java:120)
    at rubyjit.Moped::Cursor$$each_d5f9c42b1face54b312ef523ec7d172d14df4a341680052247.block_0$RUBY$__file__(/apps/tomcat7/webapps/calcengine/WEB-INF/lib/promotionlibs.jar!/gems/moped-2.0.6/lib/moped/cursor.rb:28)
    at rubyjit$Moped::Cursor$$each_d5f9c42b1face54b312ef523ec7d172d14df4a341680052247$block_0$RUBY$__file__.call(rubyjit$Moped::Cursor$$each_d5f9c42b1face54b312ef523ec7d172d14df4a341680052247$block_0$RUBY$__file__)
    at org.jruby.runtime.CompiledBlock19.yield(CompiledBlock19.java:135)
    at org.jruby.runtime.Block.yield(Block.java:142)
    at org.jruby.RubyArray.eachCommon(RubyArray.java:1606)
    at org.jruby.RubyArray.each(RubyArray.java:1613)
    at org.jruby.RubyArray$INVOKER$i$0$0$each.call(RubyArray$INVOKER$i$0$0$each.gen)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callBlock(CachingCallSite.java:143)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callIter(CachingCallSite.java:154)
    at rubyjit.Moped::Cursor$$each_d5f9c42b1face54b312ef523ec7d172d14df4a341680052247.__file__(/apps/tomcat7/webapps/calcengine/WEB-INF/lib/promotionlibs.jar!/gems/moped-2.0.6/lib/moped/cursor.rb:28)
    at rubyjit.Moped::Cursor$$each_d5f9c42b1face54b312ef523ec7d172d14df4a341680052247.__file__(/apps/tomcat7/webapps/calcengine/WEB-INF/lib/promotionlibs.jar!/gems/moped-2.0.6/lib/moped/cursor.rb)
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.JittedMethod.call(JittedMethod.java:161)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callBlock(CachingCallSite.java:143)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:149)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callVarargs(CachingCallSite.java:112)
    at rubyjit.Moped::Query$$each_d665770547ce0f382a5745553bf408aff9fba0e91680052247.__file__(/apps/tomcat7/webapps/calcengine/WEB-INF/lib/promotionlibs.jar!/gems/moped-2.0.6/lib/moped/query.rb:78)
    at rubyjit.Moped::Query$$each_d665770547ce0f382a5745553bf408aff9fba0e91680052247.__file__(/apps/tomcat7/webapps/calcengine/WEB-INF/lib/promotionlibs.jar!/gems/moped-2.0.6/lib/moped/query.rb)
    at org.jruby.ast.executable.AbstractScript.__file__(AbstractScript.java:38)
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.JittedMethod.call(JittedMethod.java:161)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callBlock(CachingCallSite.java:143)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callIter(CachingCallSite.java:154)
    at rubyjit.Mongoid::Contextual::Mongo$$each_2fb7a025221ceabc57ed6ee46d5f9169720ef1bd1680052247.__file__(/apps/tomcat7/webapps/calcengine/WEB-INF/lib/promotionlibs.jar!/gems/mongoid-4.0.2/lib/mongoid/contextual/mongo.rb:122)
    at rubyjit.Mongoid::Contextual::Mongo$$each_2fb7a025221ceabc57ed6ee46d5f9169720ef1bd1680052247.__file__(/apps/tomcat7/webapps/calcengine/WEB-INF/lib/promotionlibs.jar!/gems/mongoid-4.0.2/lib/mongoid/contextual/mongo.rb)
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.JittedMethod.call(JittedMethod.java:161)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callBlock(CachingCallSite.java:143)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:149)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callVarargs(CachingCallSite.java:112)
    at rubyjit.Mongoid::Contextual$$each_11e66c3e8105d85d815e0ad727a63f9bcc751bba1680052247.chained_0_rescue_1$RUBY$SYNTHETIC__file__(/apps/tomcat7/webapps/calcengine/WEB-INF/lib/promotionlibs.jar!/gems/mongoid-4.0.2/lib/mongoid/contextual.rb:20)
    at rubyjit.Mongoid::Contextual$$each_11e66c3e8105d85d815e0ad727a63f9bcc751bba1680052247.__file__(/apps/tomcat7/webapps/calcengine/WEB-INF/lib/promotionlibs.jar!/gems/mongoid-4.0.2/lib/mongoid/contextual.rb)
    at rubyjit.Mongoid::Contextual$$each_11e66c3e8105d85d815e0ad727a63f9bcc751bba1680052247.__file__(/apps/tomcat7/webapps/calcengine/WEB-INF/lib/promotionlibs.jar!/gems/mongoid-4.0.2/lib/mongoid/contextual.rb)
    at org.jruby.ast.executable.AbstractScript.__file__(AbstractScript.java:38)
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.JittedMethod.call(JittedMethod.java:161)
    at org.jruby.RubyClass.finvoke(RubyClass.java:528)
    at org.jruby.runtime.Helpers.invoke(Helpers.java:484)
    at org.jruby.RubyEnumerable.callEach(RubyEnumerable.java:96)
    at org.jruby.RubyEnumerable.injectCommon(RubyEnumerable.java:844)
    at org.jruby.RubyEnumerable.inject(RubyEnumerable.java:865)
    at org.jruby.RubyEnumerable$INVOKER$s$inject.call(RubyEnumerable$INVOKER$s$inject.gen)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callBlock(CachingCallSite.java:177)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callIter(CachingCallSite.java:188)
    at rubyjit.Module$$pickrules4Order_c2ca99d7f8cf0e55c79920f16524fb2bc5fa6e261680052247.__file__(/apps/tomcat7/webapps/calcengine/WEB-INF/classes/rubysrc/libs/extservice/rulepickservice.rb:30)
    at rubyjit.Module$$pickrules4Order_c2ca99d7f8cf0e55c79920f16524fb2bc5fa6e261680052247.__file__(/apps/tomcat7/webapps/calcengine/WEB-INF/classes/rubysrc/libs/extservice/rulepickservice.rb)
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.JittedMethod.call(JittedMethod.java:141)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:134)
    at org.jruby.ast.CallNoArgNode.interpret(CallNoArgNode.java:60)
    at org.jruby.ast.InstAsgnNode.interpret(InstAsgnNode.java:95)
    at org.jruby.ast.OpAsgnOrNode.interpret(OpAsgnOrNode.java:102)
    at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)
    at org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)
    at org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:74)
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:139)
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:187)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:306)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:136)
    at org.jruby.ast.CallNoArgNode.interpret(CallNoArgNode.java:60)
    at org.jruby.ast.CallNoArgBlockNode.interpret(CallNoArgBlockNode.java:60)
    at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)
    at org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)
    at org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:74)
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:182)
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:203)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:326)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:170)
    at org.jruby.ast.CallOneArgNode.interpret(CallOneArgNode.java:57)
    at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)
    at org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)
    at org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:74)
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:182)
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:203)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:326)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:170)
    at rubyjit.Module$$extended_a101d7e78a6d16d879f757b2f66326d7dc77a3641680052247.method__0$RUBY$calc(/apps/tomcat7/webapps/calcengine/WEB-INF/classes/rubysrc/libs/calcengine/calcengine.rb:86)
    at rubyjit$Module$$extended_a101d7e78a6d16d879f757b2f66326d7dc77a3641680052247$method__0$RUBY$calc.call(rubyjit$Module$$extended_a101d7e78a6d16d879f757b2f66326d7dc77a3641680052247$method__0$RUBY$calc)
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DynamicMethod.call(DynamicMethod.java:210)
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.CompiledMethod.call(CompiledMethod.java:263)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:326)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:170)
    at rubyjit.Promotion::ExportService::CalcEngineService$$_calc_61bbcc14aeb853713fd02cfabafc5e9069431d631680052247.__file__(/apps/tomcat7/webapps/calcengine/WEB-INF/classes/rubysrc/libs/calcengine/calcengineservice.rb:82)
    at rubyjit.Promotion::ExportService::CalcEngineService$$_calc_61bbcc14aeb853713fd02cfabafc5e9069431d631680052247.__file__(/apps/tomcat7/webapps/calcengine/WEB-INF/classes/rubysrc/libs/calcengine/calcengineservice.rb)
    at org.jruby.ast.executable.AbstractScript.__file__(AbstractScript.java:46)
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.JittedMethod.call(JittedMethod.java:221)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:202)
    at org.jruby.ast.FCallTwoArgNode.interpret(FCallTwoArgNode.java:38)
    at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)
    at org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)
    at org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_BLOCK(ASTInterpreter.java:112)
    at org.jruby.runtime.Interpreted19Block.evalBlockBody(Interpreted19Block.java:206)
    at org.jruby.runtime.Interpreted19Block.yield(Interpreted19Block.java:194)
    at org.jruby.runtime.Interpreted19Block.yield(Interpreted19Block.java:177)
    at org.jruby.runtime.Block.yieldArray(Block.java:158)
    at org.jruby.RubyBasicObject.yieldUnder(RubyBasicObject.java:1588)
    at org.jruby.RubyBasicObject.instance_exec19(RubyBasicObject.java:1562)
    at org.jruby.RubyBasicObject$INVOKER$i$0$3$instance_exec19.call(RubyBasicObject$INVOKER$i$0$3$instance_exec19.gen)
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DynamicMethod.call(DynamicMethod.java:202)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callBlock(CachingCallSite.java:143)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:149)
    at org.jruby.ast.CallNoArgBlockPassNode.interpret(CallNoArgBlockPassNode.java:53)
    at org.jruby.ast.MultipleAsgn19Node.interpret(MultipleAsgn19Node.java:104)
    at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)
    at org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)
    at org.jruby.ast.IfNode.interpret(IfNode.java:116)
    at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)
    at org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)
    at org.jruby.ast.RescueNode.executeBody(RescueNode.java:221)
    at org.jruby.ast.RescueNode.interpret(RescueNode.java:116)
    at org.jruby.ast.BeginNode.interpret(BeginNode.java:83)
    at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)
    at org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)
    at org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_BLOCK(ASTInterpreter.java:112)
    at org.jruby.runtime.Interpreted19Block.evalBlockBody(Interpreted19Block.java:206)
    at org.jruby.runtime.Interpreted19Block.yield(Interpreted19Block.java:194)
    at org.jruby.runtime.Interpreted19Block.call(Interpreted19Block.java:125)
    at org.jruby.runtime.Block.call(Block.java:101)
    at org.jruby.RubyProc.call(RubyProc.java:290)
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.ProcMethod.call(ProcMethod.java:64)
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DynamicMethod.call(DynamicMethod.java:180)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:70)
    at org.jruby.ast.CallSpecialArgNode.interpret(CallSpecialArgNode.java:73)
    at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)
    at org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_BLOCK(ASTInterpreter.java:112)
    at org.jruby.runtime.Interpreted19Block.evalBlockBody(Interpreted19Block.java:206)
    at org.jruby.runtime.Interpreted19Block.yield(Interpreted19Block.java:194)
    at org.jruby.runtime.Interpreted19Block.call(Interpreted19Block.java:125)
    at org.jruby.runtime.Block.call(Block.java:101)
    at org.jruby.RubyProc.call(RubyProc.java:290)
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.ProcMethod.call(ProcMethod.java:64)
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DynamicMethod.call(DynamicMethod.java:180)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:70)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callVarargs(CachingCallSite.java:106)
    at rubyjit.RubyCalcEngineService$$doPost_5d45f7976c9cb30a0905497450f9788c033264211680052247.__file__(/apps/tomcat7/webapps/calcengine/WEB-INF/classes/rubysrc/irubyservice.rb:62)
    at rubyjit.RubyCalcEngineService$$doPost_5d45f7976c9cb30a0905497450f9788c033264211680052247.__file__(/apps/tomcat7/webapps/calcengine/WEB-INF/classes/rubysrc/irubyservice.rb)
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.JittedMethod.call(JittedMethod.java:221)
    at org.jruby.RubyClass.finvoke(RubyClass.java:761)
    at org.jruby.runtime.Helpers.invoke(Helpers.java:506)
    at com.ibm.commerce.cbt.promotion.RubyCalcEngineService.doPost(RubyCalcEngineService.java:88)
    at com.ibm.commerce.cbt.promotion.CalcEngineWrapper.doPost(CalcEngineWrapper.java:44)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:957)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:620)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    - locked <0x00000000e6448d98> (a org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapper)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - <0x0000000085b1b8a8> (a java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker)
```

Comment: JRuby by default should only do interpreting the first time it sees the script ... however there might be a try to load a compiled version of the file, but that should not be an issue. since you guys did a "deep dive" JVM analysis I'm not sure the native stack is the best thing to showcase - maybe a a few call-traces might be better esp. since you're asking this on JRuby's issue tracker.

Comment: Hi, I captured a java call stack, it shows the thread wait on java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1 method, which is a native interface as mentioned in my question. I update the question with this java stack

Comment: it really seems like you're doing eval-style method changes at runtime .. and since its coming from your own .rb code there's not much I can help without knowing what's going on. likely, if there's a way you could avoid (singleton) method updates, your issues should go away.

Comment: Hi Kares, thank you for kindly suggestion. I'd like to ask a bit more details, do you mean my issue is caused by the ruby code being updated in runtime, so the jruby interpreter has to interpret it every time and it invokes the jvm class loading logic? I got this information from coder of my team, that he uses much "self.extended" code style to extend base class behavior. not sure whether this is method updates or eval-style you've mentioned?

Comment: yes - that might be it.